# Question on the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim \frac{s_n - s}{s_n + s} = 0$, then prove that $\lim s_n = s$.

This is from Analysis with an introduction to proof, chapter 2(sequences), section 1. I have to prove this by only using the definition of convergence + a theorem which states if $|s_n - s| \leq k(a_n)$, provided that k > 0 and $\lim(a_n) = 0$, then $\lim s_n = s$.

$t_n = \frac{s_n - s}{s_n + s}$. Then, we have $(t_n)(s_n + s)=s_n - s$

$s_n t_n + st_n = s_n - s$

$s_n(t_n - 1) = -s(1+t_n)$

And then we have $s_n = \frac{(s)(1 + t_n)}{1 - t_n}$

$s_n - s = \frac{(s)(1 + t_n)}{1 - t_n} - s$

$s_n - s = \frac{s + st_n - s + st_n}{1 - t_n} = \frac{2st_n}{1 - t_n}$

Comment: Let $t_n=(s_n-s) /(s_n+s) $. Can you express $s_n$ solely in terms of $t_n$ and $s$? If yes then you are done!

Comment: Actually yes, I did it. But after that idk. I forgot to mention, that was the hint in the book. But still I'm stuck there.

Comment: Please find $s_n$ as indicated in my last comment and then find $s_n-s$. Do the algebra and post it in your question. I will help you find $k>0$ needed here.

Comment: I isolated s_n.

Comment: Great $s_n-s=2s\cdot\frac{t_n}{1-t_n}$

Comment: Oh. So now we just have to do the part where lim(tn/1 - tn) = 0?. Hm, but how? any hints?

Comment: Well the denominator $1-t_n$ can be made greater than $1/2$ and hence $|s_n-s|\leq 4(|s|+1)|t_n|$ and your $k=4(|s|+1)$.

Comment: Are the downvotes related to the question being treated as PSQ? IMHO this is rather different as the asker engages in discussion and is attempting a solution.

Answer (score 3):

we have $$\frac{s_n-s}{s_n+s}=1-\frac{2s}{s_n+s}$$
So :
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{2s}{s_n+s}\right)=0\\
\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2s}{s_n+s}=1\\
\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(s_n+s\right)=2s\\
\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}(s_n-s)=0\\
\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=s\\
\end{align*}